# Omit unrelated key from type involving unions

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a call interface that describes its arguments using some fixed properties and some unioned variants.

```
type P1 = {prop1: number}
type P2 = {prop2: number}
type U1 = {u1: string}
type U2 = {u2: number}
export type Args = P1 & P2 & (U1 | U2)
```

I want to write a signature where one of the fixed properties is omitted (because a default is being supplied from elsewhere).

Naïvely, I would try `Omit<Args, 'prop1'>`, but that doesn't preserve the union correctly.  And the part types are not exported, so simply brute forcing it as `P2 & (U1 | U2)` isn't practical.

Most answers I find on this subject are about [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), but I don't want to touch the union part at all.  Is there any way to modify an unrelated property while retaining the original structure of the union without having to redeclare it?

I want something like this to work:

```
type CurriedArgs = ??? // everything from Args except prop1
const partial: CurriedArgs = {prop2: 1, u1: ''} // or {prop2: 1, u2: 1}
const complete: Args = {prop1: 42, ...partial}
```

Comment: What specifically about the other answers fails to meet your needs? Hopefully it’s something like “the following code produces an unexpected error/lack-of-error” and not “I don’t like how the type is *displayed*”

Comment: To be clear, [this is the "distributive" version of `Omit`](https://tsplay.dev/WozLem), and it gives you `type CurriedArgs = Omit<P1 & P2 & U1, "prop1"> | Omit<P1 & P2 & U2, "prop1">` which is exactly equivalent to the type you're looking for, it just *displayed* the same way. What specifically is the issue with that, if there is one?

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't have access to the part types, but the mapped key answer looks like the approach I need.  (The distributive answers I came across were concerned with modifying the unions themselves.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapped type will preserve the union.

To filter out properties you can use the `as` clause. If it resolves to never no property is generated.

```
type P1 = {prop1: number}
type P2 = {prop2: number}
type U1 = {u1: string}
type U2 = {u2: number}
export type Args = P1 & P2 & (U1 | U2)

type RemoveFromUnion<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends keyof U ? never : K]: T[K]
};

type CurriedArgs = RemoveFromUnion<Args, P1>;

const test: CurriedArgs  = {prop2: 5, u2: 6}
const test2: CurriedArgs = {prop2: 5, u1: "hello"}
```

Comment: Since the part types are not exported, and I have to go by property name, I think what I specifically need is:  `type RemoveFromUnion<T, U extends keyof T> = { [K in keyof T as K extends U ? never : K]: T[K] }` but your answer demonstrates the necessary approach, thanks!